# Trouble with table formatting in HTML email

Tags: html, email

I got a script which displays disk space on all servers on a HTML page, and side-by-side sends email from the content of the html File saved.

HTML file is perfect, the email displays the tabular information same in the html file

However, the tables are overlapping in the email.... code as below.

Thanks in advance.

```
$freeSpaceFileName = "c:\script\FreeSpace.htm"
$serverlist = "c:\script\computers.txt"
$warning = 50
$critical = 30
New-Item -ItemType file $freeSpaceFileName -Force
# Getting the freespace info using WMI
#Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk  | Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3} | format-table DeviceID, VolumeName,status,Size,FreeSpace | Out-File FreeSpace.txt
# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeHtmlHeader
{
param($fileName)
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
Add-Content $fileName "<html>"
Add-Content $fileName "<head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>"
Add-Content $fileName '<meta http-equiv="refresh" CONTENT="5">'
Add-Content $fileName '<title>All Servers DiskSpace Report by Taher Tamboli &copy;</title>'
add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">'
add-content $fileName  "<!--"
add-content $fileName  "td {"
add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;"
add-content $fileName  "font-size: 20px;"
add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "body {"
add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;"
add-content $fileName  ""
add-content $fileName  "table {"
add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "-->"
add-content $fileName  "</style>"
Add-Content $fileName "</head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<body>"
add-content $fileName  "<br></br>"
add-content $fileName  "<table width='100%' align=center>"
add-content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
add-content $fileName  "<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>"
add-content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='5'><strong>All Servers DiskSpace Report by Taher Tamboli 2014 &copy; - $date</strong></font>"
add-content $fileName  "</td>"
add-content $fileName  "</tr>"
add-content $fileName  "</table>"
add-content $fileName  "<br></br>"
}

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeTableHeader
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Drive</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='50%' align='center'>Drive Label</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Total Capacity(GB)</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Used Capacity(GB)</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Free Space(GB)</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Freespace %</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}

Function writeHtmlFooter
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "</body>"
Add-Content $fileName "</html>"
}

Function writeDiskInfo
{
param($fileName,$devId,$volName,$frSpace,$totSpace)
$totSpace=[math]::Round(($totSpace/1073741824),2)
$frSpace=[Math]::Round(($frSpace/1073741824),2)
$usedSpace = $totSpace - $frspace
$usedSpace=[Math]::Round($usedSpace,2)
$freePercent = ($frspace/$totSpace)*100
$freePercent = [Math]::Round($freePercent,0)
 if ($freePercent -gt $warning)
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"

 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$freePercent</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
 elseif ($freePercent -le $critical)
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
 #<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center>
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
 else
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FBB917' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
 # #FBB917
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
}
Function sendEmail
{ param($from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName)
$from=New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "xxx@cc.com"
$to= New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "ccc@...com"
$subject="Servers Disk space report - $Date" 
$smtphost="smtp.google.com"
$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true
$smtp.Send($msg)

}

writeHtmlHeader $freeSpaceFileName
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist)
{
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server</strong></font></td>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "</tr>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<br>"
 writeTableHeader $freeSpaceFileName

 $dp = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $server |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3}
 foreach ($item in $dp)
 {
 Write-Host  $item.DeviceID  $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size
 writeDiskInfo $freeSpaceFileName $item.DeviceID $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size

 }
}
writeHtmlFooter $freeSpaceFileName
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
sendEmail xxx@test.com xxx@test.com "Disk Space Report - $Date" hub1 $freeSpaceFileName
```

[image: *#*#*#*##* CLICK HERE FOR ERROR #*#*#*#*#*#*#]

Comment: What is the exact HTML which is sent in the e-mail, which is rendered that way? Which e-mail client are you using? Which PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: As it appears its working in Outlook OWA not in Outlook client...

Comment: I'm guessing the output HTML is not entirely correct. Could you edit your question and include the HTML generated?

Comment: I think I might have to live with that as Outlook is using word rendering for the HTML output.I thought it was something with the code although the output is perfect with Outlook OWA and HTML page......anyway I'll try to post the HTML output ASA i get the chance..... thanks @robert.westerlund